# Select each SQL column individually using loop in python and store them in a list

Tags: python, sql-server, list, loops

I want to create a data frame for each SQL column and store them in a list. Since my data is huge, I am loading them in chunks and then appending them

I have tried using the following:

```
###create a list first
numdata={}  
vars=['INITIAL_AMOUNT','LINE_AMOUNT','OUTSTANDING_DEBT'] ##these are names of few column in my sql table  
###loop over sql columns and store them in a list                         
for names in vars:
    chunks=pd.read_sql('SELECT names FROM mydb.dbo.mytable', conn, chunksize=100000)
    numdata[names]=pd.concat(chunks)
```

I am expecting to get something like:

```
     INITIAL_AMOUNT LINE_AMOUNT 
0    600.0000  13500.2870
1    700.0000  1500.7567
2    500.0000  6409.0557
3    500.0000  12700.2870
....
```

but what I do get is just names of variables for each row as below:

```
0    INITIAL_AMOUNT LINE_AMOUNT 
1    INITIAL_AMOUNT LINE_AMOUNT 
2    INITIAL_AMOUNT LINE_AMOUNT 
3    INITIAL_AMOUNT LINE_AMOUNT
```

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Try changing your `SELECT` to `'SELECT [' + names + '] FROM mydb.dbo.mytable'`. And I must say that if you have enough memory to append the columns in python, I don't see a reason to get them from sql-server one by one in the first place, but that's your call.

Comment: @Aryerez Worked! Thank you! Even though I don't have enough memory to append all the columns, at least I can summarize each column individually for the moment.